# Sqoop export to SQL Server. Updates and Inserts. Sqoop export updates records on SQL Server which are same

Tags: azure-sql-database, sqoop

I have 10010 records on HDFS and 10000 records on SQL Server.
The extra 10 records in HDFS are inserts and some of the records are updates. 
Rest of the records are same.

During sqoop export, does sqoop export updates records on SQL Server which are same?

The export I am running is

```
sqoop export --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://myserver.database.windows.net:1433;username=adminsql@myserver;password=pass;database=db1" --table FACTS_COUNTRY --update-key ID --update-mode allowinsert --export-dir /FACTS_COUNTRY/ --escaped-by \\ --optionally-enclosed-by '\"' --input-fields-terminated-by ","
```

Comment: It would help if you captured the commands being run against the backend database.  SQL Server/Azure does have some optimizations to avoid making updates to the exact same value in an existing row, but without knowing the commands it is hard to comment further.

Comment: Have you tried the "--incremental append" arguments?

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo the --incremental append seems to works only for imports.